# How can I get a free UK IP address?

Tags: ip-address, vpn

I live in Germany, work for a real estate broker. I would like to list some of our properties on Gumtree.co.uk, however they don't allow submissions from outside of UK - they are automatically blocked because of non-UK IP address.

Is there a way to do this without paying? If not, what paid service would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

The best option would be to use a VPN since many 'free proxies' can stop at anytime and often are incredibley slow.

Most VPNs are pay as you go and charge monthly so your not tied into any contracts and most are fast if its a paid service. I recommend paying but firstly trying free trials which most offer and see how you get on. If its slow then try another one.

Heres a few

1. http://www.uk2.net/vpn/ (Paid but is fast)
2. http://vpnuk.co.uk/ (Free Trial)
3. http://www.watchuktv.co.uk/ (Free Trial)
4. http://www.afreevpn.com/ (Free)
5. http://www.getukvpn.com/ (Free)
6. http://www.bestvpnservice.com/uk-vpn-service.php (Big List of VPNs in UK)

Enjoy ;)

Comment: Thanks, it really helped. I got it to work with a free one, quite fast as well.